# hist(add = TRUE) showing different scales with similar data

Tags: r

I'm using add=TRUE with the hist() function but the second histogram seem to be in another scale, altough both data are from the normal distribution.

With ggplot I got the result I wanted. Why the hist() isn't showing the same result?

-->> [result screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB4hE.png)

```
# Random data
set.seed(100)
dataset1=rnorm(4000 , 100 , 30)     
dataset2=rnorm(4000 , 200 , 30) 

# Histograms BASE R

hist(dataset1, breaks=30 , xlim=c(0,300) ,  col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5) , xlab="Altura" , ylab="Peso" , main="")
hist(dataset2, breaks=30 , xlim=c(0,300) , col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),  xlab="Altura" , ylab="Peso" , main="",add = TRUE)

#Histograms GGPLOT

library(tidyverse)
dataset3 = bind_rows(ds1 = list(a = dataset1), ds2 = list(a = dataset2), .id = 'df')

dataset3 %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, fill = df))+
  geom_histogram(alpha = .5, position = 'identity', color = '#e9ecef')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specify `breaks=30`, that's just a suggestion. The `hist()` function will adjust that number to better fit the data. Plus when you call `hist()` on each data set independently, the breaks will be different for each histogram. In your base, there are 41 breaks used for `dataset1` and 26 for dataset2. These very different bin sizes mean you get very different pictures. More bins = lower overall heights.

This is different than `ggplot` where you have just one `geom_histogram` so you only get one set of breaks. The breaks are very important because that determines just how many points will fall within the bins. If you want everything to match, you should use a shared set of breaks for all plots

```
breaks <- seq(0, 320, length.out=20)

hist(dataset1, breaks=breaks , xlim=c(0,300) ,  col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5) , xlab="Altura" , main="")
hist(dataset2, breaks=breaks , xlim=c(0,300) , col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),  xlab="Altura" ,  main="",add = TRUE)

dataset3 %>% ggplot(aes(x = a, fill = df))+
  geom_histogram(alpha = .5, position = 'identity', color = '#e9ecef', breaks=breaks)
```

[image: base R histogram]
[image: ggplot histogram]

Answer (score 3):

You have to apply `ylim = c(0,600)`

```
hist(dataset1, breaks=30 , ylim = c(0,600), xlim=c(0,300) ,  col=rgb(1,0,0,0.5) , xlab="Altura" , ylab="Peso" , main="")
hist(dataset2, breaks=30 , ylim = c(0,600), xlim=c(0,300) , col=rgb(0,0,1,0.5),  xlab="Altura" , ylab="Peso" , main="",add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: But why is the heigth is so different? Using ggplot the heigth is almost the same.

Comment: That is a result of different binning applied.

Comment: Quite busy here. Thanks Till and Mr. Flick for the answer